# Strange behaviour NSTableView Delegate and cell identifiers

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

I'm trying to build NSTableView with different rows. I added two table cell views and set Identifiers, Delegate and DataSource is linked to delegate.

[image]

While Identifiers are set to **OTFType** and **OTFTag** delegate method `tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject?` is never called. But number of rows set by `numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int` is OK

When I delete Identifiers method `tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn...` is called but throws an error (of course).

Identifiers set:

```
rows: 96
```

Program continues, TableView has proper number of rows but they are empty.

Identifiers not set:

```
rows: 96
Hello, is this method called?
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Program stops.

Here are my delegate methods:

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    print ("rows:", tableArrayController.arrangedObjects.count)
    return tableArrayController.arrangedObjects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {

    print("Hello, is this method called?")

    let tableContent = tableArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [AnyObject]
    let item  = tableContent[row]
    if  item.className == OpenTypeFeature.className() {
        print("className = \(item.className)")
        let button:NSButton = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("OTFTag", owner: self) as! NSButton
        button.title = (item as! OpenTypeFeature).tag
        button.integerValue = 1 //TO DO later
        return button
    } else if  item.className == OpenTypeFeaturesType.className() {
        print("className = \(item.className)")
        let textField:NSTextField = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("OTFType", owner: self) as! NSTextField
        textField.stringValue = (item as! OpenTypeFeaturesType).name
        return textField
    }

    return nil

}
```

Any hints?

Comment: `objectValueForTableColumn` should return an object value. `viewForTableColumn` should return a table cell view. You are returning a button or a textfield.

Comment: The identifier of the column and the table cell view should be the same. If you don't set them, they are automatic.

Comment: Willeke, thanks a lot, I have small progress: have filled rows with generic checkboxes OR textfields — how it is possible to have two different cell identifiers when both they have to be same as a column identifier? Tricky? Impossible?
I subclassed NSTableCellView, added NSButton outlet, connected to checkbox. But changing **cell.checkBox.title**, **.. .integerValue** or  **cell.textField.stringValue** (in NSTableCellView)  causes no effect.

Comment: Set the identifier of one view to automatic and set the other to a custom identifier.